# Wix run command line extract from .tar.gz

Tags: command-line, wix, tar, gzip

I have wix setup below.

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
          <Product Id="*" Name="SomeApplication" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Company" UpgradeCode="4810b5e4-21d8-4a45-b289-eafb10dddc0a">
            <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

            <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
            <Media Id="1" Cabinet="Cab1.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />

            <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="EvokoInstaller" Level="1">
              <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
            </Feature>

            <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />
            <WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="LICENSE.rtf" />

            <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLFOLDER" />

            <InstallExecuteSequence> 
               <Custom Action="ExtractService" Before="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
            </InstallExecuteSequence>
            <CustomAction Id="ExtractService" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" Execute="deferred" ExeCommand="7z e some_service.tar.gz  && 7z x some_service.tar" Return="check"/>

          </Product>

          <Fragment>
            <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
              <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                 <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="SomeInstaller"/>
              </Directory>
            </Directory>
          </Fragment>

          <Fragment>
            <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
              <Component Id="packages">
                <File Source="some_service.tar.gz" />
              </Component>
            </ComponentGroup>
          </Fragment>
    </Wix>
```

Now it is copying some_service.tar.gz file to installation directory. I would like to extract the file once it is copied. I would like it to be done automatically by Wix.

Command `7z e some_service.tar.gz  && 7z x some_service.tar` does it for sure when I do it manually and command prompt is started as aministrator.

How can I execute it from Wix and delete compressed files once it is extracted.

EDIT1:

After @ArkadySitnitsky's comment I have add the proposed code and now I can not copy some_service.tar.gz file to installation destination.

Please check the image:

[image]

EDIT2:

Here is log from event logger after installation stoped with error.

> Product: SomeProduct -- Error 1722. There is a problem with this Windows >Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not
>   finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. 
>   Action ExtractService, location: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\SomeInstaller\, command: 7z e some_service.tar.gz

EDIT3:

When I add pause at the end of command
like this: `ExeCommand="7z e some_service.tar.gz pause"` I am again able to install it. It does copy .tar.gz and leaves it as it is.

EDIT4:

Regarding compresed file deletion after extraction is done I have tried:

```
<CustomAction Id="ExtractService3"
              Directory="INSTALLFOLDER"
              Impersonate='no'
              Execute="deferred"
              ExeCommand="rm liso_service.tar.gz"
              Return="check"/>

<CustomAction Id="ExtractService4"
              Directory="INSTALLFOLDER"
              Impersonate='no'
              Execute="deferred"
              ExeCommand="rm liso_service.tar"
              Return="check"/>
```

and

```
  <Custom Action="ExtractService3" After="ExtractService2">NOT Deleted</Custom>
  <Custom Action="ExtractService4" After="ExtractService2">NOT Deleted</Custom>
```

But again it results withe the same worning popup. Can you please advise on this.

EDIT5:

```
 <Custom Action="ExtractService3" After="ExtractService2"></Custom>
  <Custom Action="ExtractService4" After="ExtractService2"></Custom>
```

still the same result

EDIT6:

`rm` command was not working when I tried it manually and it reported error:

> cygintl-2.dll is missing from your computer

I have read on other post that it is because of OpenSHH not being properly installed. I must not have OpenSHH as dependency, so I uninstalled it. After that `rm` command was unrecognized. Thus, I have tried `del` command (manually ). It works, but only it Command Prompt is run as administrator.

EDIT7:

`ExeCommand="del /f /q some_service.tar.gz"` results with the same popup. But in installation folder there is only **some_service.tar** it seems that **some_service.tar.gz** is deleted. When I try to manually delete `del /f /q some_service.tar` it says

> Access is denied.

EDIT8:

I am already trying to delete both files .tar and tar.gz. See below please:

```
    <CustomAction Id="ExtractService"
              Directory="INSTALLFOLDER"
              Impersonate='no'
              Execute="deferred"
              ExeCommand="7z e -y some_service.tar.gz"
              Return="check"/>

<CustomAction Id="ExtractService2"
              Directory="INSTALLFOLDER"
              Impersonate='no'
              Execute="deferred"
              ExeCommand="7z x -y some_service.tar"
              Return="check"/>

<CustomAction Id="ExtractService3"
              Directory="INSTALLFOLDER"
              Impersonate='no'
              Execute="deferred"
              ExeCommand="del /f /q some_service.tar.gz"
              Return="check"/>

<CustomAction Id="ExtractService4"
              Directory="INSTALLFOLDER"
              Impersonate='no'
              Execute="deferred"
              ExeCommand="del /f /q some_service.tar"
              Return="check"/>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="ExtractService" Before="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
  <Custom Action="ExtractService2" After="ExtractService">NOT Installed</Custom>
  <Custom Action="ExtractService3" After="ExtractService2" ></Custom> 
  <Custom Action="ExtractService4" After="ExtractService2" ></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: Have you tried to run the Custom action with Execute="deferred"?

Comment: @ArkadySitnitsky I have just tried and the same thing happens. Nothing.

Comment: Your Custom action is not scheduled, try to add: 
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action='ExtractService' Before='InstallFinalize'>NOT Installed</Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>

Comment: Actually, not I am unable to perform installation at all. it stops in the middle of it with a working popup. Please check popup image in the question.

Comment: Great, this is means your custom action ran. Now try the deffered option if no success, add the log lines regarding the error

Comment: @ArkadySitnitsky Please check my last edit. What would be the other options?

Comment: @ArkadySitnitsky it seems that deffered option is not working. Could you please give me a hint.

Comment: Your command is targeting tar.gz  try "del /f /q some_service.tar"

Comment: @ArkadySitnitsky No, I still can not delete compressed files. Thanks for asking. Please check my few last edits.

Comment: I think it's cannot be done that way. You should try to use binary element to save the file and then run custom action. check the link http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/How-to-delete-a-file-for-temp-use-after-installation-td693017.html

Comment: @ArkadySitnitsky thank you very much. I did not have time to do this any more until now. I will take a look now and let you know. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have ran the code and you should use the custom action like this:

```
<CustomAction Id="ExtractService" 
              Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" 
              Impersonate='no' 
              Execute="deferred" 
              ExeCommand="&quot;[INSTALLFOLDER]7za.exe&quot; e -y cheeseburger.7z" 
              Return="check"/>

<CustomAction Id="ExtractService2" 
              Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" 
              Impersonate='no' 
              Execute="deferred" 
              ExeCommand="&quot;[INSTALLFOLDER]7za.exe&quot; x -y cheeseburger.7z" 
              Return="check"/>
```

copy this custom action and and set the exe command as needed.

Also make custom action for each operation, dont use &&.
Simply copy the custom action above, give different id name and add it to the Sequence.

```
        <InstallExecuteSequence> 
           <Custom Action="ExtractService" Before="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
           <Custom Action="ExtractService2" After="ExtractService">NOT Installed</Custom>
        </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Hope it helped

Comment: Please check my last edit regarding compressed file deletion.

Comment: You need to remove the condition "NOT deleted".

Comment: Check if manual removal works, if not check the log. also you can open the msi with orca and check the custom action table...

Comment: Try to use the del command inside the installer and use also /F /Q to force  and do not promp with yes/no...

Comment: ExeCommand="del /f /q some_service.tar.gz" results with the same popup.